# UIButton with title and image centered

Tags: uiimageview, uibutton, uilabel, title

I want a UIButton with image **and** title. I got the text appearing using `-setTitleEdgeInsets`.

But I don't want to use trial and error to get the right position because the title of the button should be dynamic. I tried to determine the size and position of the UIButtons titleLabel object and set the titleEdgeInsets corresponding to it with the following code:

```
[myButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(myButton.center.y - (myButton.titleLabel.bounds.size.height / 2),
                             - (myButton.center.x - (myButton.titleLabel.bounds.size.width / 2)),
                             myButton.center.y + (myButton.titleLabel.bounds.size.height / 2),
                             myButton.center.x + (myButton.titleLabel.bounds.size.width / 2))];
```

Am I missing or misusing something here?

Thanks in advance, with kind regards -Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons can be a bit of a pain in how they manage their label and image subviews - it doesn't give you much control. This is because they update these values whenever the button state changes (or even more often) so if you have set the parameters manually your settings get lost. This is why you need to use methods like `setTitleEdgeInsets:` - you are on the right track. :)

Things to watch out for:

- Your use of `myButton.center` is probably incorrect. That would be the center of your button in its parent view, you probably want to use half the button size here.
- It may be the case that when your code is called the button hasn't done its subview layout yet so hasn't already set the frame/bounds for the `titleLabel`.

You could call `layoutSubviews` on the button, and/or `sizeToFit` on the label. However, you're really at the mercy of the opaque implementation details of `UIButton`, so it might be best to calculate what you think the text/label size will be (using one of the `sizeWithFont:*` methods in `NSString`) and set a top and left edge inset to position the text.